Django Python - How to Query this
I have this Consumer model
class ConsumerModel(models.Model):
    GENDER_LIST = (
        ('male','MALE'),
        ('female','FEMALE'),
        ("lgbt",'LGBT')
    )
    REGISTER_AS = (
        ('consumer','CONSUMER'),
        ('manager','MANAGER')
    )

    uid = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    # remove the default value some time
    profile_id = models.UUIDField()
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=GENDER_LIST,null=True,blank=True)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to="images/")
    register_as = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False,choices=REGISTER_AS, max_length=12)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user

I have this view where I want to look/print for the Consumer with the following user but it returns and error:
serializer = ConsumerLoginSerializer(data=request_data)

        if serializer.is_valid:
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=request_data["email"])
            except:
                return Response(data={'status': wrong_input, 'message':wrong_body_vals_msg, 'errors':{"Email":"User not found"}})
            
            print("PROFILE ID: " + ConsumerModel.objects.get(user=user))
            return Response(data={"status": ok, 'message': "Success"}, status=ok) 


what error are you getting? Show us your serializer too

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

is_valid is a method not a property.
serializer.is_valid returns a method reference, so it is always true, even though user submitted data is incorrect.
so, Instead it should be a method call
if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
# rest of your code

when you use serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True), it validates the data against the serializer. If data passes validation, it continues execution, if the data fails validation, it raises a ValidationError exception instead of returning a boolean value (True or False).
